# Right-Click on Dynamically created RadioButtons

Tags: c#, xaml

On my application I am able to dynamically create Radio Buttons and I need to have the ability to add a right click to each dynamically created button.

For an example button I added the below code would have the right click as needed.
XAML:
`<RadioButton Content="3001" x:Name="myButton" Width="75" Height="40" FontSize="25" ContextRequested="MyButton_ContextRequested"/>`

C# Code Behind:

```
private void ShowMenu(bool isTransient)
        {
            FlyoutShowOptions myOption = new FlyoutShowOptions();
            myOption.ShowMode = isTransient ? FlyoutShowMode.Transient : FlyoutShowMode.Standard;
            CommandBarFlyout1.ShowAt(myButton, myOption);
        }

private void MyButton_ContextRequested(Windows.UI.Xaml.UIElement sender, ContextRequestedEventArgs args)
        {
            // always show a context menu in standard mode
            ShowMenu(true);
        }
```

Dynamic Button Add -
XAML:

```
              <StackPanel x:Name="SiteAddPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top">

                <Button PointerEntered="Button_PointerEntered" PointerExited="Button_PointerExited" Width="80" Height="45">
                    <muxc:AnimatedIcon x:Name="SearchAnimatedIcon">
                        <muxc:AnimatedIcon.Source>
                            <animatedvisuals:AnimatedFindVisualSource/>
                        </muxc:AnimatedIcon.Source>
                    </muxc:AnimatedIcon>
                    <Button.Flyout>
                        <Flyout
                            x:Name="flyoutSiteID">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBox
                                    x:Name="seachSiteID"
                                    Header="Enter the 4 Digit Site Number"
                                    PlaceholderText="SiteID"
                                    >
                                    
                                    <TextBox.KeyboardAccelerators>
                                        <KeyboardAccelerator Key="Enter" Invoked="KeyboardAccelerator_Invoked"/>
                                    </TextBox.KeyboardAccelerators>
                                </TextBox>
                                <Button VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="Add_Site">
                                    <SymbolIcon Symbol="Add">
                                    </SymbolIcon>
                                    <!--<Button.KeyboardAccelerators>
                                        <KeyboardAccelerator Key="Enter"/>
                                    </Button.KeyboardAccelerators>-->
                                </Button>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Flyout>
                    </Button.Flyout>
                </Button>
                <AppBarSeparator Width="20"/>
                
            </StackPanel>
```

C# Code Behind:

```
        private void Add_Site(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var btnName = "btnSite" + seachSiteID.Text;

        if (SiteAddPanel.Children.Count <= 6)
        {
            RadioButton button = new RadioButton();
            button.Name = btnName;
            button.Width = 75;
            button.Height = 40;
            button.FontSize = 25;
            button.Content = seachSiteID.Text;

            SiteAddPanel.Children.Add(button);

            seachSiteID.Text = "";
            flyoutSiteID.Hide();

        }
    }
```

I have been trying to add MyButton_ContextRequested to each one of the dynamic buttons and haven't had much luck.

This is what the menu bar looks like:
[MenuBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxpT1.png)

Comment: button.ContextRequested += MyButton_ContextRequested; doesn't work?

Comment: I had thought I did try that, but after comparing what you wrote vs what I wrote I see that my context was off... Here is what I had `button.ContextRequested contextRequested = MyButton_ContextRequested;`

Solved :)

Comment: Well, what you had before is essentially the same as writing button.Text text = "foo"; it doesn't make sense to give a name to something you are assigning to.